# Unable to connect non-system databases in rstudio

Tags: r, odbc, rstudio

I've been trying to connect DB(sql server management studio) to rstudio.
This is what i have tried

```
    # Importing and listing the drivers usiang the ODBC 
library(odbc)
odbcListDrivers()
sort(unique(odbcListDrivers()[[1]]))

# Database connection using DBI
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect( odbc(),
                  Driver = "SQL Server",
                  Server="localhost\\SQLEXPRESS",
                  Database="master",
                  Trusted_Connection="True"
                 )
```

The above code successfully connects to the db but i can see only the system databases under the connection tab. The non-system db the user defined ones are not show in the connection panel of the R studio. How to fix this.

[Connections panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57ph4.png) 
[Non-system dbs in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeeMP.png)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: I wonder if the backslash should be escaped, does `Server="127.0.0.1\\\\SQLEXPRESS"` work?